# ¿Cómo consigo la ruta de acceso de un archivo?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms

Intento obtener la ruta de acceso de un archivo a partir de un Open File Dialog.
Es decir, yo tengo un archivo llamado hola.txt. Quiero obtener su ruta de acceso (C:/users/currentUser/Desktop/hola.txt).
¿Cómo consigo obtener ese path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si seleccionas el archivo por medio del `OpenFileDialog` debes usar la propiedad

[OpenFileDialog](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog?view=netframework-4.8)

```
using (OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog())
{
    openFileDialog.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";

    if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        filePath = openFileDialog.FileName;

        //resto codigo
    }
}
```

usas la propiedad `FileName` pero no retorna solo el nombre sino la ruta completa

[FileDialog.FileName Propiedad](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filename?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Forms_FileDialog_FileName)

En los comentario dice:

> El nombre de archivo incluye la ruta de acceso del archivo y la extensión. Si no se selecciona ningún archivo, este método devuelve una cadena vacía ("").

Comment: Vale, ¡muchísimas gracias! Eso resolvió mi duda.

Answer (score 0):

Según la [documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder?view=netframework-4.8), tienes que acceder a las carpetas especiales de windows, en tu caso (escritorio del usuario) se trata de `DesktopDirectory` que está en el enumerador `Environment.SpecialFolder`

Por lo tanto, el path correcto debería ser

```
string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory) + '\\hola.txt';
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la información. No es lo que buscaba, pero muchas gracias de igual forma.